# Fixing maven Java heap space error

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

Long story short, I have a maven project which runs fine if I use:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
```

but without it I get:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ project ---

...

An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Now I would like to move that configuration to the pom file.
I have tried two possibilities:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <meminitial>512m</meminitial>
        <maxmem>2048m</maxmem>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

...

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

None of this worked.

Is there another way of handling the `-Xmx` parameter from the pom file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use `<fork>true</fork>` in your configuration as you cannot influence the memory settings in the process you are currently running in.